# Vue - Pulling index back from nested component for pushing to array

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm encoding images to base64 in a component which is then pushed the the related array.

Parent Component

```
<v-tab-item v-for="(item, index) in colItems" :key="index">

 <base64 :index="index" :multiple="true" :done="getFiles(index)">
```

```
colItems: [
  title: '',
  colItemImgs: '',
]
```

Simplified Child Component

```
  <div>
    <v-btn raised @click="onPickItemFile(index)">base64</v-btn>
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" style="display: none" ref="64input" />
  </div>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
    done: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => {}
    },
    index: '',
  },
  methods: {
    onChange (e) {
     // Removed base64 reader images for simplification

     let files = e.target.files;

           let fileInfo = {
              name: file.name,
              type: file.type,
              size: Math.round(file.size / 1000)+' kB',
              base64: reader.result,
              file: file
           }
           let index = this.index

           allFiles.push(fileInfo)

           if(allFiles.length == files.length){

              if(this.multiple) this.done(allFiles)
              else this.done(allFiles[0])
           }
        } 
     } 
  }, 
  onPickItemFile (index) {
    this.$refs.base64Input.click()
  },
```

My issue is that I'll need to add and delete imgs in an existing array, but can't get the index back to the parent component.

Anyone that can help, it would very appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the start and desired end conditions are. It looks like colItems is an array, where each element represents multiple files? What array needs to be added to and deleted from?

Comment: Hey @RoyJ, Desired outcome is to have a colItem which holds a title, subtitle and a list of images which are to be uploaded in the base64 format. These images will need to be removed and added to an existing ColItem.

Comment: What gets remove and what gets added? Generally, the child should `$emit` its result and the parent should handle it.

Comment: @RoyJ has got the right idea for using `$emit`. If you need to emit an event to a parents parent and don't want to chain events `provide / inject` may be the way to go. Check it [out](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject)

Comment: Thanks guys, $emit worked! Appreciate your time